# How can I reformat messages in an mbox file with bash or Perl?

Tags: perl, bash, mbox

I have a huge mbox file, with maybe 500 emails in it.

It looks like the following:

```
From x@blah.com Fri Aug 12 09:34:09 2005
Message-ID: <42FBEE81.9090701@blah.com>
Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2005 09:34:09 +0900
From: me <x@blah.com>
User-Agent: Mozilla Thunderbird 1.0.6 (Windows/20050716)
X-Accept-Language: en-us, en
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: someone <someone@hotmail.com>
Subject: Re: (no subject)
References: <BAY101-F9353854000A4758A7E2CCA9BD0@phx.gbl>
In-Reply-To: <BAY101-F9353854000A4758A7E2CCA9BD0@phx.gbl>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Status: RO
X-Status: 
X-Keywords:                 
X-UID: 371
X-Evolution-Source: imap://x+blah.com@blah.com/
X-Evolution: 00000002-0010

Hey

the actual content of the email

someone wrote:

> lines of quotedtext
```

I would like to know how I can remove all of the quoted text, strip most of the headers except the To, From and Date lines, and still have it somewhat continuous.

My goal is to be able to print these emails as a book sort of format, and at the moment every program wants to print one email per page, or all of the headers and quoted text. Any suggestions for where to start on whipping up a small program using shell tools?

Comment: You don't show one, but if there isn't a blank line between the headers and the body, you're in deep doo-doo.

Comment: hey is counted as the body, so it should be fine?

Comment: In your example, nothing will be able to tell where the body begins.  In RFC-822, the body is defined by the blank line before it.

Comment: But there is a blank line between "Hey" and the evolution header?

Comment: It wasn't visible to me when I wrote those messages.  Not sure if that's because I was at work where I'm forced to use IE, or somebody edited it.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at it at work again, and the blank line has disappeared.  Must be a bug in IE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mail::Box::Mbox](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Mail-Box-2.084/lib/Mail/Box/Mbox.pod) will let you easily parse the file into separate messages.  Mark Overmeer's [slides from YAPC::Europe 2002](http://perl.overmeer.net/yapc2002-mailbox/img0.html) go into quite a bit of detail as to why parsing is much more difficult than it seems.  Using this library will also deal with mh, IMAP and many other formats than just mbox.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Mail::Box::Manager;

    my $file = shift || $ENV{MAIL};
    my $mgr = Mail::Box::Manager->new(
        access      => 'r',
    );

    my $folder = $mgr->open( folder => $file )
    or die "$file: Unable to open: $!\n";

    for my $msg ($folder->messages)
    {
        my $to      = join( ', ', map { $_->format } $msg->to );
        my $from    = join( ', ', map { $_->format } $msg->from );
        my $date    = localtime( $msg->timestamp );
        my $subject = $msg->subject;
        my $body    = $msg->body;

        # Strip all quoted text
        $body =~ s/^>.*$//msg;

        print <<"";
    From: $from
    To: $to
    Date: $date
    $body

    }
```

You may want to reconsider your request to strip the quoted text -- what if you email that is formatted with interleaved replies?  Stripping the quoted text would make this sort of email very hard to understand:

```
  Foo wrote:
  > I like bar.

  Bar?  Who likes bar?

  > It is better than baz.

  Everyone knows that.

  -- 
  Quux
```

Additionally, what do you plan to do with attachments, non-text/plain MIME types, encoded text entities and other oddities?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are no attachments for printing, all text is in english and most mail is not interleaved with quotes, which will save a lot of paper

Comment: Just q quick question, but does that perl take a parameter, or does it use the $MAIL environment variable

Comment: The script does take a parameter (my $file = shift) or if none is given it defaults to the environment variable (|| $ENV{MAIL}).

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want, but for two things. The emails do not appear to be chronologically ordered, however they are in the original file, and there are a lot of  =20 at the end of lines that I would like to remove..

Comment: actually, scratch that, they are not in chronological order in the original file...damnit I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Is there any easy way to sort the messages chronologically?

Comment: The =20 are due to it not being text/plain, but instead quoted-printable.  You would need to use a MIME parser to convert them and reformat, or if =20 is the only special case '$body=~s/=20$//msg;'.  For sorting you can do something like 'for(sort { $a->timestamp <=> $b->timestamp } @$folder) {...}'

Answer (score 1):

As a start, I would probably use "formail" to extract the mails with just the headers you want.  Either that, or use some sort of state table in awk to see if you're in the header or not, and either strip everything but the wanted headers if you're in the header and strip the quotes if you're not.

Comment: Hudson's answer is better than mine.  Which brings up a meta question: should we delete our answers when something better comes along, or only when your answer is "bad"?

Answer (score 1):

Using shell tools may not be the best answer to that as there are many libraries in many languages to deal with mbox, be it in Ruby, Perl or whatever.  You will have to also consider that quoting characters are not always "> " which can screw up your de-quoting process.  As for extracting the headers you want, this should not be difficult in any language.  I know this is a general answer, maybe not specific enough...