# How can I sort an mbox file by date?

Tags: perl, mbox

I would like to know how to modify the below code to strip `=20` characters at the end of many lines, and mainly to sort the messages chronologically from first received or sent to last. I am not sure if this would be an internal Perl routine or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Mail::Box::Manager;

my $file = shift || $ENV{MAIL};
my $mgr = Mail::Box::Manager->new(
    access          => 'r',
);

my $folder = $mgr->open( folder => $file )
or die "$file: Unable to open: $!\n";

for my $msg ($folder->messages)
{
    my $to          = join( ', ', map { $_->format } $msg->to );
    my $from        = join( ', ', map { $_->format } $msg->from );
    my $date        = localtime( $msg->timestamp );
    my $subject     = $msg->subject;
    my $body        = $msg->body;

    # Strip all quoted text
    $body =~ s/^>.*$//msg;

    print <<"";
From: $from
To: $to
Date: $date
$body

}
```

When trying to run this I get the following errors:

"my" variable $msg masks earlier declaration in same scope at x.pl line 16. 
syntax error at x.pl line 15, near ") ) "
syntax error at x.pl line 31, near "}" 
  (Might be a runaway multi-line << string starting on line 25)
Execution of x.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

I am not sure as to why, as the syntax seems fine.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368003/how-can-i-reorder-an-mbox-file-chronologically

Comment: no, this is for perl, and more specific

Comment: Did you read my comment to your question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356763 about using sort { $a->timestamp <=> $b->timestamp } to change the ordering in the for loop?  When I cut-n-paste the code above it works fine for me with no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that those instances of `=20` are in the body of the message. Reading just a bit of the [documentation for Mail::Message](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Mail-Box/lib/Mail/Message.pod) will reveal this helpful note:

> BE WARNED that this returns you an object which may be encoded: use decoded() to get a body with usable data.

Thus instead of calling `$msg->body` in your loop, simply call `$msg->decoded->string`.

Accomplishing sorting should be easiest when you use `Mail::Message::timestamp`:

```
...
for my $msg ( sort { $a->timestamp <=> $b->timestamp } $folder->messages) )
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am unsure how to make use of decoded() however

Comment: This is workingbeautifully, however I can not open the file with gedit. Is there a way to assign a character set to the file being written to?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to look at the [MIME::Base64](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/MIME-Base64-Perl-1.00/) module which includes MIME::QuotedPrint::Perl module to decode QP bodies.